# Solution differential equation E&M wave

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

i am wondering why we only consider a particular solution of the equation of em wave. I mean we have the 4 maxwell equations and we want to resolve them. Then we suppose the electric field is perpendicular to the magnetic field and then we see that they have to satisfy the wave equation (that with the v² terms), and then we suppose that they are on the form of sinus (expressed as A_0 * sin(...)).

So why do we suppose the perpendicularity? and why do we suppose the form of the solution? i mean the solution of the wave equation are not only this form!! and also, we made the assumption for the wave equation that the angles were small (to have sin x = x), so how can we know that em waves dont not big angles?

rmq: wave equation : d²y/dt² = v² * d²y/dx²

Comment: In deriving the wave equation for electromagnetism, there is no small-angle approximation. You seem to be thinking about the wave equation for a vibrating string.

Comment: Fourier analysis shows that all waves can be considered sums of sine waves with various amplitudes, frequencies, and phases.

Comment: i don't understand... f(x, t) = t is a solution of the wave equation but is not a sum of sine ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maxwell equations are,
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot{}\vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0},\ \ \ \ 
\vec{\nabla}\cdot{}\vec{B} = 0,$$
$$\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{E} = -\frac{\partial{\vec{B}}}{\partial{t}},\ \ \ \ 
\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{B} = \mu_0\vec{j} + \epsilon_0\mu_0 \frac{\partial{\vec{E}}}{\partial{t}}.$$

For free (that is, empty) space we have
$$\rho=0,\ \ \ \ \vec{j} = 0.$$
which transforms the initial equations to form
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot{}\vec{E} = 0,\ \ \ \ 
\vec{\nabla}\cdot{}\vec{B} = 0, \tag{1,2}$$
$$\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{E} = -\frac{\partial{\vec{B}}}{\partial{t}},\ \ \ \ 
\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{B} = \epsilon_0\mu_0 \frac{\partial{\vec{E}}}{\partial{t}} \tag{3,4}.$$

Any electric and magnetic field must obey these laws on free space. So we can combine them to form a result. First, take the curl of $(3)$:
$$\vec{\nabla}\times{}(\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{E}) = -\vec{\nabla}\cdot{}\frac{\partial{\vec{B}}}{\partial{t}}$$

Time derivative and gradient can interchange order:
$$\vec{\nabla}\times{}(\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{E}) = -\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{t}}\,(\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{B})$$

Inserting $\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{B}$ from $(4)$ gives,
$$\vec{\nabla}\times{}(\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{E}) = -\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{t}}\,(\epsilon_0\mu_0 \frac{\partial{\vec{E}}}{\partial{t}}) = -\epsilon_0\mu_0 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \vec{E}$$

From the identity that
$$\vec{A}\times(\vec{B}\times\vec{C}) = \vec{B}\,(\vec{A}\cdot{C}) - \vec{C}\,(\vec{A}\cdot{B})$$
$$\vec{\nabla}\times{}(\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{E}) = \nabla\,(\nabla\cdot{\vec{E}}) - (\nabla\cdot\nabla)\vec{E} = -\epsilon_0\mu_0 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \vec{E}$$

We know that for free space, $\nabla{\vec{E}} = 0$, so
$$\Delta \,\vec{E} = \epsilon_0\mu_0 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \vec{E}$$
$$\mathbin\Box\,\vec{E} = 0. \tag{5}$$

where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator, which is $\nabla\times\nabla$, and $\mathbin\Box$ is the d'Alembertian operator as defined as
$$\mathbin\Box := \Delta - \frac{1}{v^2}\,\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{t}^2},$$ whose solutions are of form $f(\mathbf{r},t) = A\,\sin(\omega{t}-\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}+\phi)$.

Notice that $v$ in $(5)$ is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}$, which, as it turns out, is the speed of light.

---

As for why $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{B} = 0$, i.e. they are perpendicular, we need to check a few things:

First, the wave equation's solutions are oscillations that always stay in the same direction., regardless of the partial derivatives of either variable. Therefore let's assign these directions $\hat{E}$ and $\hat{B}$ for $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$. Then, let's check equation $(3)$:
$$\vec{\nabla}\times{}\vec{E} = -\frac{\partial{\vec{B}}}{\partial{t}}$$

Since the right hand side is on direction $\hat{B}$, so should the left hand side. But, here we see that the direction of the LHS is perpendicular to of $\vec{E}$ because of the cross product (from the curl operation).

This means that,
$$\hat{B} \perp \hat{E}$$
which was your second question.

Notice; there were no assumptions other than free space, which is the case for a EMW in vacuum.

Comment: i am sorry but forget to tell i have no idea what gradient is, in my lessons we use integrals

Comment: @jean marc Okay then, did you follow why $\hat{E}\perp\hat{B}$? This was a result of a cross product. Then, uhm, the only two possible solutions to the wave equation are the ones we already suggested (the sin and cos forms). This follows from the fact that wave equation is a secon order differential equation

Comment: oh yeah ok i think i have understood!!